# How to return a class?

Tags: java, class

I have this code in my `main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Customer forrest = new Customer("Forrest Gump", 1, "42 New Street, New York, NY"); 
        Customer random = new Customer("Random Name", 2, "44 New Street, New York, NY"); 
...
}
```

how can i proceed to writing code so it returns an instance of the customers given an id number (say 1 given returns forrest, 2 given returns random)

Comment: Are you saving the Customer in a database? Otherwise the Customers forrest and random only exist in the scope of the main method.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas hmmm... for now im just manually adding customers (there are only 2 customers in this case), later I might try writing an Customer input interface...i'd like to get an universal approach, suppose idk the instance name of the 1st customer was `Forrest`, how do i make the program return Forrest given the int id was 1?

Comment: You're confusing class names and variable names.  In Java, it's standard practice to capitalize class names but not variable names.  `Forrest` and `Random` should not be capitalized.  So this is confusing because you are returning `Customer`, which seems to be a class itself.  I think you want to return `Forrest`, there actually.  But this error would stand out a lot better following capitalization standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use static fields or if it may throw an exception write static block in your class. Please never start variable name from capital letter.

```
class MainClass{
    // All uppercase because it is constant
    private static final Customer FORREST = new Customer("Forrest Stallings", 1, "42 New Street, New York, NY"); 
    private static final Customer RANDOM = new Customer("Random Name", 2, "44 New Street, New York, NY"); 

     public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }
```

If you want to return class

```
 Class returnClass(){
 if(sth)
    return Customer.class;
 else
    return Random.class;
 }
```

Comment: can you take a look again at the code, I've added some details to make my question more clear

Answer (score 3):

When you create your Customer objects in main, they only exist in main unless you save them somewhere.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Customer c = new Customer ( ... );
    // c exists here
}
public static void doSomething() {
    // c does not exist here
}
```

Unless you save your new objects into a database or a data structure, you won't be able to do some sort of "lookup" on them.

Here's an example where you can save the Customers based on their ids in a HashMap:

```
private HashMap<Integer, Customer> records = new HashMap<Integer, Customer>();

public void doSomething() {
    Customer forrest = new Customer(1); 
    Customer random = new Customer(2);

    // put the customers in the HashMap:
    records.put(1, forrest);
    records.put(2, random);

    // to get them out:
    records.get(1); // returns forrest
    records.get(2); // returns random
}
```

Comment: can you take a look again at the code, I've added some details to make my question more clear

Comment: @user133466 -- Why don't you just modify the Customer class to hold a BankAccount object? eg. `public class Customer{ private BankAccount account; ... }` ?

Comment: i actually have 4 BankAccount object in the Customer class. A more detailed code can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316042/how-to-get-an-instance-of-a-class

Comment: @user133466 - So if you have the bank account in the customer, and you have the customer, why don't you just query the customer for its bank account? eg. `customer.getAccountC()` ??

Answer (score 1):

In this case your `return` statement should be object of type.

Example:

```
return new Customer();
```

Unless `Customer` and `Random` related (inheritance), you may NOT be able to write a method which returns both types.

Comment: i'd like to get an universal approach, suppose idk the instance name of the 1st customer was `Forrest`, how do i make the program return Forrest given the `int id` was 1?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what are you asking. I suspect you are going to return instance of the class, created object. Then write `return Forrest;` Forrest object is visible only in method main scope

Comment: i'd like to get an universal approach, suppose idk the instance name of the 1st customer was `Forrest` (neither do i know the instance name of the 2nd customer was `Random`), how do i make the program return `Forrest` given the int id was 1

Comment: can you take a look again at the code, I've added some details to make my question more clear

Answer (score 1):

```
static Customer GetCustomer(int id)
```

The return type of this method doesn't mean that you have to return the `Customer` class.

It means that, it should return a reference to an object of class Customer, or a subclass of Customer.

So, your return statement should be like: -

```
return new Customer(id);
```

And, based on the method, it seems like it should return an already existing `Customer` object with that `id`. For e.g., if you have a `List<Customer>`, then you would need to find out from that list a `Customer` object having the given `id`.

Now, given that in your main method, you have created two `Customers` - `forrest` and `random`. You need to save those references in some persistence storage, either a `List<Customer>` or some database. And to get the reference pointing to an object based on some `id`, you would have to fetch it from the persistence storage in use.

---

In your case, since you want to fetch the object based on `id`, you can maintain a `Map<Integer, Customer>` to store your `Customers` with their particular `id`.

```
static Map<Integer, Customer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Customer>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Customer forrest = new Customer("Forrest Stallings", 1, "42 New Street, New York, NY"); 
    Customer random = new Customer("Random Name", 2, "44 New Street, New York, NY"); 

    map.put(1, forrest);
    map.put(2, random);
}
```

And then in your `getCustomer` method, just get the `customer` for the `id` passed as parameter:-

```
public Customer getCustomer(int id) {
    return map.get(id);
}
```

So, you don't need to do a test on the `id` for any value. It will automatically fetch the corresponding `Customer` for that `id`.

For e.g.: -

```
getCustomer(1);
```

Will return the object pointed to by `forrest` reference.

Comment: can you take a look again at the code, I've added some details to make my question more clear

Answer (score 0):

if GetCustomer was an instance method, it would be:

```
Customer GetCustomer(int id){
    Customer result = null;

    if(id == 1){
        result = Forrest ;
    }else if(id == 2){
        result = Random;
    }

    return result;
}
```

but you can't access instance variables from a static method, like you are trying to

So what you might want to do is construct each object within the method rather than rely on their existing instance:

```
static Customer GetCustomer(int id){
        Customer result = null;

        if(id == 1){
            result = new Customer("Forrest Stallings", 1, "42 New Street, New York, NY"); 

        }else if(id == 2){
            result = new Customer("Random Name", 2, "44 New Street, New York, NY");
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: can you take a look again at the code, I've added some details to make my question more clear

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make the classes as class variables:

```
 private static Customer forest; 
 private static Customer random; 

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    forrest = new Customer("Forrest Stallings", 1, "42 New Street, New York, NY"); 
    random = new Customer("Random Name", 2, "44 New Street, New York, NY"); 
    ...
  }
```

Then:

```
 static Customer GetCustomer(int id){
    if(id == 1){
       return customer;
    }else if(id == 2){
       return random;
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you take a look again at the code, I've added some details to make my question more clear

Comment: @user133466: Do you mean there are `Forrest` and `Random` sub classes of `Customer` class and based on the `id` being passed, you want to instantiate the right class?

Comment: forrest and random are instances of the class Customer. Sorry for capitalizing them. A more detailed code can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316042/how-to-get-an-instance-of-a-class

Comment: @user133466 I just answered that question. Please check the answer and let me know, if that doesn't help.